# How to add new column to order grid using observers?

Tags: mysql, magento, collections, adminhtml

Could you help me? I'm trying to add new column to the order grid in admin using observers. 
there is my config.xml

```
    <adminhtml>
        <events>
            <adminhtml_block_html_before>
                <observers>
                    <order_grid>
                        <type>model</type>
                        <class>Order_Grid_Model_Observer</class>
                        <method>addItemsColumn</method>
                    </order_grid>
                </observers>
            </adminhtml_block_html_before>
        </events>
    </adminhtml>
```

There is my observer code:

```
class Order_Grid_Model_Observer
{
    public function addItemsColumn($observer)
    {
        $_block = $observer->getBlock();
        $_type = $_block->getType();
        if ($_type == 'adminhtml/sales_order_grid') {
            $_block->addColumn('total_item_count', array(
                'header'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('Items'),
                'width' => '80px',
                'type'  => 'text',
                'index' => 'total_item_count',
                'sortable' => false,
                'filter' => false
            ));
            $_block->getColumn('real_order_id')
                ->setData('filter_index', 'main_table.increment_id');

            $collection = $_block->getCollection();
            $collection->clear();
            $collection->getSelect()
                ->joinLeft(array('o' => 'sales_flat_order'), 'o.entity_id = main_table.entity_id', array('total_item_count'));
            $_block->setCollection($collection);
        }
    }
}
```

And I almost did it, but when I try to sort grid by some field, I get the error "Column 'increment_id' in field list is ambiguous". It's weird because I've updated 'filter_index' for 'increment_id' field. Any ideas why collection for this block was not updated? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"We" (another group) implemented an extension on a [Magento Hackathon](http://magento-hackathon.de) which allows to easily add new columns, rearrange them and remove columns from the grid. Furthermore you can join tables to the collection to add columns.

https://github.com/magento-hackathon/GridControl

Comment: Thanks for the great work! However, this doesn't seem filtering or sorting the added column.

Comment: Depends on how you add the column. IF you are not able to make it work, open an issue - the projects looks uncared, but if we find time we'll check on it.